# How to achieve Caching a pandas data frame value between REST API calls?

Tags: pandas, caching, redis

We are building an application that process huge amount of data and returns the result to the user [ WEB / TAB / MOBILE].

Front End - Angular
Back End - Django REST
DataBase - Mysql / Oracle

We need to query the DB and keep the data in memory or cache using a dataframe. So that the subsequent API calls might apply some filters are grouping operations in that dataframe.

Please help if such scenario is possible and is there a better way to achieve this objective.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try saving it as a temporary csv using df.to_csv() and pd.read_csv()? You can even zip it.

Comment: Thanks Tyler K. Have kept this as an option and exploring redis , django cache as well. Will revert back if i get a break through